# Why does my .where statement does not work with a join in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, where-clause

In my app Im having a query to determine if a games has likes,

```
@games = Like.select('l.*').where(:game_id => @game.id).joins('join likes l on likes.user_id=l.likes and l.user_id=likes.likes')
```

The game needs to have a certain id and 2 users both have to like the game

The first where(:game_id => @game.id) does not work though it returns results from multiple game.id's how can I fix that?

Comment: Why are you joining the likes table onto itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had stablished the relationship between the two models like this:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :likes
end

class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :game
end
```

Then in your controller you just need:

```
@game = Game.find_by_id(game.id)
@likes = @game.likes.count
```

Anyway in this case I think that maybe the best approach  would be to use add likes as an attribute and use counter_cache_column.